# Difference between Kie Server, Business Central and Kie Workbench?

Tags: jbpm, business-process-management, kie-workbench, kie-server

I am new to **jBPM**.

I have developed and deployed a Business Process through Business Central (KIE Workbench) only and it is working fine. **I haven't used Kie Server directly.**

I wanted to know the difference between **Kie Server and Business Central.**

Can I develop and deploy Business Process, rules, etc. without Business Central (KIE Workbench)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Kie-server provide execution environment for execution of rules and processes, it didnt support authoring of rules and processes. business-central(known as kie-workbench in community) support authoring and execution of process and rules in 6.x release. From 7.x release, kie-workbench didnt support execution of rules and processes, it support only authoring.